Movie in which hero puts bet with an Asian guy for guessing jersey number of players correctly
I watched this movie 2 years back. Don't remember any names. It's a Hollywood movie. The hero in the climax puts bet with an Asian guy that he will be able to  guess the jersey number of  player in the game they are watching from stands. The heroine can choose the number and convey it to the Asian guy.
The film starts with a test to heroine to see whether she can join the gang of robbers which the hero is part of.
EDIT  It's an English movie. The guessing game with Asian guy happens like 3 times and the hero loses the first two guesses. Everything was pre planned by the hero's gang

Welcome to Movies&TV. Do you remember release year, language, country or other plot details, any at all? Add them so that it can help identify this movie. Also see How to ask Identify-this-X questions.

@AJ Its english movie. The guessing game with asian guy happens like 3 times and the hero loses the first two guesses. Everything was pre planned by the hero's gang.

Also see this question to understand how to ask.

I think you are talking about Focus (2015)

Jess follows Nick to New Orleans, where she is introduced to Nicky's crew as well, including the obese and profane Farhad (Adrian Martinez). She picks a few pockets as a test, and soon Nicky and Jess develop a romantic relationship, upsetting Nicky, who was taught by his father to never become emotionally involved with anyone in their line of business. At the 17th Associated Football Franchise of America Championship Game at the Mercedes-Benz Superdome, Nicky gets into a round of increasingly extravagant bets with gambler Liyuan Tse (B.D. Wong), eventually losing all of the money the crew has earned.
To win it back, Nicky asks Tse to pick any player on or off the field and says that Jess will guess the number picked. A distraught Jess scans the field and notices Farhad wearing jersey number 55 and realizes it is another con. They take Tse for millions of dollars. 


No. This one , its american football involved. And they have to guess jersey number of the player

[SPOILER] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwS68ixemAQ Are you sure?

@alfinthomas: This scene happens in Focus. Will Smith is making the bet agains the asian guy, and Margot Robbie is the one to guess the number.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

I would suggest, on the small info in the question, that the answer is Focus (2015)
Below is an excerpt of the plot from http://www.themoviespoiler.com

Nicky and Jess go to a football game. They make small bets with each other such as if one fan will catch a hot dog, and if another is too drunk to get up for the wave. They see a woman in short shorts and bet how many men will look at her ass as she walks by. Jess bets 8 while Nicky bets 3. 
  A curious man named Mr. Liuyan (BD Wong) joins the game and bets 5. 
  Seven men check out the woman as she walks by, making Jess the closest. Liuyan makes more bets with Nicky over the game, practically begging him to play when Nicky tries to back out. Nicky plays and loses $1000. 
  The bets escalate as the two men double the bets, even as Jess tells Nicky they should just leave. Just when it looks like he's about to lose it all, Nicky bets all of his money, including Jess's, which amounts to about $1.1 million, for a quick card game. Liuyan pulls the card with a higher number, winning all their money. 
  Nicky chooses not to walk away and decides to double the bet if Liuyan picks any player on the field and he makes Jess pick the one that Liuyan spotted. Liuyan gives them a chance to back out, but Nicky makes Jess pick. Jess grabs a pair of binoculars and looks carefully through the field before spotting Farhad wearing a jersey with 55 on it. She picks him, and to everyone's surprise, that's the correct answer.

Followed by the set up portion

On the cab ride home, Nicky, now with a LOT of money on him, explains to Jess that this was set up from the beginning of the day. He knew that Liyuan is a notorious gambler, so he had it set up so that Liuyan would see the number 55 throughout the day, thereby subconsciously getting him to pick that number when the moment was right.

